# How to convert HttpGet to HttpPost?

Tags: android, http-post, http-get

I'm using HttpGet method for retrieving data from a web service from my Android app. Can anyone tell me how to convert the below given code to HttpPost method?

```
    String url = URLEditor.encode("http://"+Constants.strURL+"Orders.asmx/CheckWebConnection?TechCode="+username+"&TechPIN="+password);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if(entity == null) return false; 
    is = entity.getContent();
```

Thanks in advance...

---

thanks for helping me..

I tried with the code given above. But I get Document object as NULL. This's the code

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://"+Constants.strURL+"Orders.asmx/CheckWebConnection");
    List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvpList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TechCode", techcode));
    nvpList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TechPIN", techpin));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvpList));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

I get doc as NULL. No issues when I use HttpGet. How can it be solved? Please help

Comment: If the web service doesn't respond to POST, you're going to be out of luck. There's isn't really any "switching" from GET to POST; they're different http methods. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, this will help you.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TechCode",username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TechPIN",password));
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+Constants.strURL+"Orders.asmx/CheckWebConnection");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: it seems my webservice doesn't support HttpPost. Can anyone tell me how to do the same using SOAP?